# Docker jenkins not accessible from host browser

Tags: docker

I have docker running on centos vm(on vmware) with host machine of windows. I can able to ping centos vm IP address from host(windows) machine ip.

I tried below on centos vm,

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000  jenkins/jenkins

2020-11-21 18:41:28.924+0000 [id=27]    INFO    jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
2020-11-21 18:41:29.116+0000 [id=20]    INFO    hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Below is the output of "docker ps"

```
# docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
16a6d00b0933        jenkins/jenkins     "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   bhaskara
```

But when i try to access from host machine(windows) browser like below,

```
http://centos_vm_ip:8080
```

Am getting like "Site can't be reached"

Also, On centos vm I have opened port 8080

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eno16777736
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 80/tcp 8080/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Any idea, how to solve this issue?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to configure port forwarding in VMware, so you can access Jenkins from your host.

Comment: I configured port forwarding in VMware, still not able to access from host browser.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have followed the steps mentioned [Configuring a Web server on a virtual machine that uses NAT mode networking](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2006955)